# Reading the request body of a POST request in controller in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, api-design, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am prototyping an API implementation and running into a basic issue of not being able to read a `JSON` object that I passed in the request body from `Fiddler` .  My implementation is based on some of the examples I found across different beginner tutorials.

This is my call to the API :

```
https://{Something}/servername/{something1}/checkAvailability?{api-version}
```

It is a **POST** request and the **request body** is(JSON) : *{name:"resource1", option:"include"}*

The way I am trying to parse it at the Controller is using [FromBody]. However, the [FromBody] parametr is always read as null:

```
    [HttpPost]
    // A bunch of other attributes.
    public HttpResponseMessage CheckAvailability(
        string serverName,
        [FromBody] CheckProperties props)
    {
        // While debugging, I am able to reach here and successfully see the serverName as "something1" which passed in the API
        if (serverName == null || serverName == "")
        {
            return CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        // Able to reach here but the value of props is read as null. What is the right way to read the request body in props(CheckNameProperties) object?
        if (props != null) // props is always null for me.
        {
            // Do something
        }
  }
```

CheckProperties.cs

```
public class CheckProperties
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public string Name{ get; set; }

        [JsonProperty]
        public string Option { get; set; }

        public CheckProperties(string name, string options)
        {
            Name = name;
            Option = options;
        }
    }
```

Instead of using an object, I have tried reading a simple string as well. But, could not read that either.

Also, if someone can share tutorials that helped them have a good basic understanding of implementing API's that would be great. Most of the tutorials I came across, talk about the API design principles rather than the approaches of implementing it.

Comment: You appear to have several naming issues above, e.g. your controller parameter is of type `CheckNameProperties` but the following class is `CheckProperties`, but I'm assuming this is related to you giving a rough idea of the problem? In your actual `CheckProperties` class, do you have a constructor that takes zero arguments?

Comment: Thanks. Yes,and that naming was a typo and have updated it now in the question. I do not have the default constructor. However, I have introduced one now and set a breakpoint inside the default constructor as well. But I am not hitting that breakpoint either.

Comment: I'm not sure if you would hit a breakpoint in the constructor or not, but I'm fairly sure that there needs to be a default one so that the serializer can create a version of the class before attempting to set properties on it. Do you at least get an object in your controller now rather than null?

Comment: No, not yet. But I just tried using POSTMAN instead of FIDDLER and can see that the object is being read properly with absolutely no changes in my code which I posted above. Thanks for you help though.